# Delphi, code example code getting list of overlapping polygons with SQL Server Spatial

Tags: sql-server, spatial

The overlap between polygons can be evaluated using SQL Server spatial `.STContains` function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stcontains-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-ver16&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-ver18)

Can I get some code sample to get the list of polygons located inside a given polygon (the record index should be the query parameter), return a list of records inside this polygon?

```
select * 
from table 
where PolygonsInside (RecordIndex = 1)
```

How to get to this SQL query?

Answer (score 1):

Your description ("overlap between polygons") doesn't necessarily match the function you've chosen (from the same documentation you've linked to, `STContains()` "Returns 1 if a geometry instance completely contains another geometry instance.".); `STIntersects()` may be a better choice.

Regardless of any of that, here's a query you'd write to find any polygon from a table that overlaps given the ID of another polygon in the same table.

```
select overlaps.ID, overlaps.Polygon
from PolygonTable as given
join PolygonTable as other
   on other.Polygon.STIntersects(given.Polygon) = 1
   and other.ID <> given.ID
where given.ID = 1;
```

That is, if you provide an ID of 1, that query will find any polygon in the table that intersects with that. Note, I've added a predicate in the join so as not to also return the polygon that has the ID provided - that may or may not be what you want but it's easily removed if you *do* want to return that one.